# Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE unresolved reference

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app that asks for user permission to access the phone storage to change the user's profile picture. However I get the "unresolved reference" error while hovering over READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Here's the line with the error message:

```
foto.setOnClickListener{
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //Process to access phone's storage
            }
        }
```

And here's the beginning of my manifest file permissions

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I don't understand why it's not recognizing the permission itself within the Manifest.permission object. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you imported the correct manifest?

Comment: @JustSightseeing I'm relatively new to Android Studio so please correct me if I'm wrong. I imported into the activity the manifest of my project which have the permissions set. Like this: import com.example.pawprints.Manifest

Comment: Use `import android.Manifest`